# how to rewrite the url in wso2esb

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am using wso2ESB to obtain a login ticket from alfresco using the alfresco username and password. After I call the service

```
http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8282/services/AlfrescoLogin
```

I have to append

```
http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8282/services/AlfrescoLogin?u=xxx&pw=xxx
```

I have defined the following service:

```
<proxy name="AlfrescoLogin" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
        <target>
            <endpoint>
                <address uri="http://XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080/alfresco/s/api/login"/>
            </endpoint>
            <inSequence>
                <rewrite>
                    <rewriterule>
                        <action value="u=xxxxx" type="set" fragment="query"/>
                        <action value="pw=xxxxx" type="set" fragment="query"/>
                    </rewriterule>
                </rewrite>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <send/>
            </outSequence>
        </target>
    </proxy>
```

But the following configuration has no effect. I've tried to set the type attribute of the action tag to append as well. And I still have to add by hand the parameters to the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following URL rewrite configuration would do the required transformation to your URL.

```
<rewrite>
    <rewriterule>
        <action value="u=xxx&amp;pw=xxx" type="set" fragment="query"/>
    </rewriterule>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to get that working, now in my server log I see the URL rewritten the way I want it (http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8282/services/AlfrescoLogin?u=xxx&pw=xxx). However those parameters don't get appended to the actual service from the backend I am calling this would be http://XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080/alfresco/s/api/login from the example in the source code..